# Can any simple graph be "super edge labeled"?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $X=(V(X),E(X))$ be a simple graph with $|V(X)|=n$ and $|E(X)|=m$.
Let $$f:V(X) \bigcup E(X)\rightarrow \{1,2,3,\ldots ,n+m\}$$ be a bijection, such that for all $x,y \in V(X)$ and $\{x,y\} \in E(X)$, we have $f(x)+f(y)+f(\{x,y\})=k$ where $k$ is fixed constant.

Suppose also that

- $\forall x \in V(X)$, we have $f(x) \in \{1,2,3,\ldots , n\}$ and
- $\forall \{x,y\} \in E(X)$ we have $f(\{x,y\}) \in \{n+1, \ldots ,m\}. $

If such an $f$ exists then graph $X$ is said to be *super edge labeled*.

Does there exist a super edge labeling for every simple graph?

Comment: I revised the formatting pretty heavily (in the future, try to stay in math mode to write things like $\forall x, y \in V(x)$; you should never have to exit and immediately re-enter math mode). I did tweak some of the wording, you might want to make sure I haven't misused any terminology (I've never heard of such a labeling scheme).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it already fails for $K_4$.
Identifying the vertices with their labels, we have vertices $1,2,3,4$.
Assume a super edge labeling exists with sum $k$.

Edge $14$ and edge $23$ both need label $k-5$, i.e. we found two edges with the same label. Contradiction.

Comment: yes, if  we try like this  we will get many examples, but What I am looking for is generalization of graphs for which we can do super edge magic labeling.

Comment: @AshwinKoodathil: This comment has no reflection in your original question, and to be honest, I still do not understand what your question is now. Are you looking for graph families that DO have a super edge labeling? Please rethink what you want to ask and change your question accordingly.